# Url in page 1 to an iframe anchor in page 2

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have the following htmls:

Page 1:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href=“page2.html#iframeanchor”></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>Lot of content multiple pages</div>
<iframe src=“page3.html”>This is multiple page as well</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 3:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>Lot of content multiple pages</div>
<a id=“iframeanchor”>Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I jump to iframeanchor from Page 1 in Page 2?

Comment: More detail: iframe is generated by jive site automatically for the html content tile (on Page2), OOB I cannot add the anchore out of the iframe body

Comment: I might add code to Page 2 which checks the url and if it has the tag name scrolls the page down - although I am wondering if there is still an easyer solution?